# Extending Typescript generic class with abstract methods

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to extend abstract generic class but I'm having trouble extending some of the methods.

Consider this:

```js
abstract class A<T,K> {

    protected abstract upload<S>(item: T): S
    protected abstract download(item: T): K

}

class B<T, K > extends A<T, K>{

    protected upload(item: T):string {
        return 'hello'
    }
    protected download(item: T): number{
        return 1

    }

}
```

The error I get for the `upload` method in class `B` is:

```
Property 'upload' in type 'B<T, K>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'A<T, K>'.
  Type '(item: T) => string' is not assignable to type '<S>(item: T) => S'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'S'.
```

for `download` method in class `B`:

```
Property 'download' in type 'B<T, K>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'A<T, K>'.
  Type '(item: T) => number' is not assignable to type '(item: T) => K'.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'K'.
      'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
```

[Typescript Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggHgCoBoBpAPgQG8AoChGhABygHsIBTeFgEwVEhngQCudZI2AdsAZWIAKAJasAtgC4EuAJQqJ1Wg2ZtWXHtDiIOjAO4A7EWLmKV6lYSoBfKijQYAQnnwJCCKQsAB6slhwYOAT+xJTaNLqs7FxCNhx2LMqqGryylgDm5PG0NFAsEAJQlggA5AAWLMgiNcVuJYn6nAhmVmkZWY4IlgIKICxQlCUlZRVVCACMxSWtrkA)

Answer (score 0):

So, both functions in class `B` here contain something you can't do.

I don't know what your final code will look like, but here's what it could resemble :

```js
abstract class A<T,K> {

    protected abstract upload<S>(item: T): S
    protected abstract download(item: T): K

}

class B<T, K > extends A<T, K>{

    protected upload<S>(item: T): S {
        // return something of type S
    }

    protected download(item: T): K {
        // return something of type K
    }

}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggHgCoBoBpAPgQG8AoChGhABygHsIBTeFgEwVEhngQCudZI2AdsAZWIAKAJasAtgC4EuAJQqJ1Wg2ZtWXHtDiIOjAO4A7EWLmKV6lYSoBfKijQYAQnnwJCCKQsAB6slhwYOAT+xJTaNLqs7FxCNuJSdizKqhoIEuTxtDQA9MUIUCwQAlCWCGCMCpUAFrKWAOYIjABmCBAAnnQseYVuhYn6nAhmVmmZ2Y7+BUVFpeWV1bX1jRAt7Z09-YP+I65AA)

Here's what's wrong in your attempt :

`upload` can't return `string`, because the return type is supposed to be `S`, which is a generic parameter of the function. Because it's a generic parameter of the function, it will be specified at the function call, so while you declare it in your class, it's still generic, not specific. So its signature must be `protected upload<S>(item: T): S`

`upload` can't return `string`, because the return type is supposed to be `K`, which is a generic parameter of the **class**. Because it's a generic parameter of the class, it will be specified at the *class instantiation*. So when you're defining the class, it is still generic. So its signature must be `protected download(item: T): K`.

Comment: So how would you go about implementing those methods?

Comment: It appears that I can't implement them in class `B` since it is also generic? I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: The last paragraph should read "`download` can't return...", though.